# Declaration of properties at runtime?

Tags: objective-c, runtime, objective-c-runtime

Is there a way to declare properties at runtime in Obj-C? I was looking for something like [`class_addMethod`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/class_addMethod) but for properties.

Comment: What on earth would the point be? They wouldn't *do* anything. You can only use properties that are declared for a type at compile time, and they're translated into method calls to do their work at runtime. The compiler wouldn't let you get or set them except through method calls, so you may as well just skip the property and add the methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common misconception is that `@property` implies code generation.  It does not.  `@synthesize` does that.  So, really, your question is likely *Is there anyway to generate setter/getter methods at runtime?*

The answer is, of course, yes and you would use exactly what you've already found.

Answer (score 0):

Properties are syntactic sugar for getter/setter methods.
You can't declare them at runtime. As a comment above said, how would you use them?
But you can declare them and add implementation at runtime.
The @synthesize keyword simply installs a default getter/setter implementation. To prevent this, use the @dynamic keyword, and provide the implementation at runtime.

You might want to look at a lighter weight approach such as intercepting messages (NSObject>>(id)forwardingTargetForSelector and related methods).

Comment: I was actually looking for the automatic KVO/KVC. There are ways to do it manually, but I eventually abandoned the approach, but meh.